# How to remove indentation in very long caption in tabularray?

Tags: captions, tabularray, longtblr

I have a table as follows. How can I format so that the caption does not have any indentation from the second line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{longtblr}
[caption = {Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Caption}, 
label={tab:typewise_WTL}]
{width = \textwidth,
colsep=2pt,
colspec= {*{9}{X[c,m]}},
columns={font=\smaller},
column{1} = {font=\smaller\bfseries},
vline{2-Y}={solid},
hline{1-Z}={solid},
rowhead = 2,
row{1-2} = {font=\smaller\bfseries},
rowsep = 1pt}
\SetCell[r=2]{c}{Type} & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{25\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{50\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{75\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{100\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  \\
& S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 \\
I & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\ 
II & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\
III & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define a new theme changing the templates related to the caption format so that both the caption text and `Table 1:` are a single paragraph, thus avoiding the default indentation.

In this way the changes have a local scope.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%****************************************       added <<<<<<<<< 
\NewTblrTheme{CaptionNotIndented}{%
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{}
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{}
     \DeclareTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{Table\hspace{0.25em}\thetable:\enskip\InsertTblrText{caption}}
}
%****************************************

\begin{document}%
    
    \begin{longtblr}
        [theme=CaptionNotIndented, % use the new theme <<<
        caption = {Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long Caption}, 
        label={tab:typewise_WTL}]
        {width = \textwidth,
            colsep=2pt,
            colspec= {*{9}{X[c,m]}},
            columns={font=\small}, % changed >> \small
        column{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},% changed >> \small
            vline{2-Y}={solid},
            hline{1-Z}={solid},
            rowhead = 2,
            row{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries},% changed >> \small
            rowsep = 1pt}
        \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Type} & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{25\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{50\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{75\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{c}{100\% of $ABC_{max}$} &  \\
        & S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 & S2 & S3 \\
        I & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\ 
        II & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\
        III & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z & X/Y/Z \\
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked!
On a different note, what is the downside of using `\smaller`? I need to have a font size smaller than `\small` and larger than `\footnotesize`.

Comment: Okay, Understood.

Comment: Unless you have another package, `\smaller` is not a LaTex command.